# Eloquent Relationships Not Working as Expected

Tags: laravel

I am trying to understand what I am missing here.

Apps migration

```
Schema::create('apps', function (Blueprint $table) {
   $table->increments('id');
   $table->integer('show_id')->unsigned()->index();
   $table->string('name');
   $table->integer('provider_id')->unsigned()->index();
   $table->timestamps();
});
```

Show migration

```
Schema::create('shows', function (Blueprint $table) {
   $table->increments('id');
   $table->string('name');
   $table->timestamps();
});
```

So I create an apps model that has the following function

```
public function Show() {
    return $this->hasOne(Show::class);
}
```

But in php artisan tinker when I do $app->Show; I get the following error:

```
Illuminate\Database\QueryException with message 'SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1 no such column: shows.app_id (SQL: select * from "shows" where "shows"."app_id" = 1 and "shows"."app_id" is not null limit 1)'
```

Am I mis-understanding the relationships?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your relation should be as:

Apps model:

```
public function show() {
    return $this->hasOne(Show::class, 'id', 'show_id');
}
```

Or it can be:

```
public function show() {
    return $this->belongsTo(Show::class);
}
```

[Docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent-relationships#one-to-one)

Answer (score 1):

You do not have an app_id in your shows migration.

edit: Taking from the [Laravel Docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent-relationships#one-to-one) and changing it to fit your situation

> Eloquent determines the foreign key of the relationship based on the model name. In this case, the  show model is automatically assumed to have a app_id foreign key.

Answer (score 1):

A one-to-one relationship consists of a `hasOne` and a `belongsTo`. The table that contains the foreign key field must be on the `belongsTo` side of the relationship.

Since your `apps` table contains the `show_id` field, it is stated that `apps` belong to `shows`, and `shows` has one (or many) `apps`.

Given this, you need to change your `Show` relationship on your `Apps` model to use the `belongsTo` relationship.

```
public function Show() {
    return $this->belongsTo(Show::class, 'show_id');
}
```

Unless you rename your relationship method so that it is lowercase (`function show()`), the second parameter is required. If you renamed the relationship, Laravel could build the proper key name and you could leave off the second parameter:

```
public function show() {
    // For belongsTo, second parameter defaults to {function_name}_id.
    return $this->belongsTo(Show::class);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your apps model :

```
public function Show() {
    return $this->belongsTo('yourmodelnamespace\Show','id','show_id');
}
```

And you need create Show model too ..
Hope it will works~~

Answer (score 0):

You can use relation like this

`public function Show() {
    return $this->hasOne(Show::class, 'id','id');
}`